# Создание тени у кнопки

Tags: html, css, css3

Ребят, подскажите как сделать такую же тень у кнопки как у Request a qoute ?

[image: sample button]

Ссылка - https://ekmixmaster.wixsite.com/ekmmnew

Comment: Конкретно там это сделано PNG-картинкой, но можно и на чистом CSS извратиться

Comment: @UModeL Е на CSS как можно это сделать? Есть у Вас идеи?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нет ничего невозможного, нужно только время. CSS3 - вещь!..

```css
body {
  background-color: #969291; margin: 0; height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png"); background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: auto;
}

a.button {
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*display: grid;
  place-items: center;*/
  height: 95px; width: 462px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font: bold 40px sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #00cd00;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: background-color .4s ease 0s;
}
a.button:hover { background-color: #38c68b; }

a.button::before,
a.button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px; z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  height: 30%; width: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00cd00;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 13px 7px #000d);
}
a.button::before { left: 190px; transform: skew(-80deg) rotate(-5deg); }
a.button::after { right: 190px; transform: skew(80deg) rotate(5deg); }

a.button>span {
  display: block;
  transform: scale(0.91, 1.55) translate(1px, 3px);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button"><span>REQUEST&nbsp; A &nbsp;QUOTE</span></a>
```